# How to align the text inside a text button at start(left end) of the screen?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose

I tried to align the text at start of screen inside the text button but for some reason I cannot do it. It aligns the text at center of Text Button no matter what.

```
TextButton(
        onClick = { /*TODO*/ },
        modifier = Modifier
            .fillMaxWidth()

    ) {
        Text(
            text = "Option A",
            style = MaterialTheme.typography.bodySmall,
            textAlign = TextAlign.Start,
            modifier = Modifier
        )

    }
```

[Expected](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ufpKX.jpg)
[Reality](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qqvwZ.jpg)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you dont want to add weight or give a modifier to the Text itself, you can wrap it in a "Box" as well which gives you more options as follows:

```
TextButton(
        onClick = { /*TODO*/ },
        modifier = Modifier.fillMaxWidth()
    ) {
        Box(modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize(), contentAlignment = Alignment.CenterStart) {
            Text(
                text = "Option A",

            )
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

The `content` of a `(Text)Button` is by default put into a `Row` with `horizontalArrangement = Arrangement.Center`. You can make your `Text` aligned to the start by making it fill the whole width of that `Row`, for example with `Modifier.weight(1F)`.

Comment: I'm a beginner and these small issues take long time sometimes.
Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

`TextAlign` only makes sense when the `Text` is filling the whole available width.

```
TextButton(
    onClick = { /*TODO*/ },
    modifier = Modifier
        .fillMaxWidth(),

) {
    Text(
        text = "Option A",
        style = MaterialTheme.typography.bodySmall,
        textAlign = TextAlign.Start,
        modifier = Modifier.fillMaxWidth(), // This is important
    )
}
```