# Center the text in the Row with the Image located close to the left of the Row

Tags: android, layout, android-jetpack-compose

I'm doing an assignment on building a login screen interface similar to the Spotify application with JetPack Compose. However, I'm having trouble centering text in a Row and the Row is inside a button. [Here is my output.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ysFVg.png)

I have tried many ways such as setting text parameters with textAlign = TextAlign.Center,... but it still doesn't work. I have tried weighting the text and adding Spacer() functions, but when I rotate the screen, the layout is not the same as the original.My desired output is for Buttons to have icons on the left and text centered on both sides.

[Image of desired layout](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8nNZ3.png)

Here is my code:

```
@Composable
fun LoginScreen(modifier: Modifier=Modifier) {
    // Define a column layout for the login screen
    Column(
        modifier = Modifier
            .fillMaxSize()
            .padding(16.dp),
        verticalArrangement = Arrangement.Bottom,
        horizontalAlignment = Alignment.CenterHorizontally
    ) {
        //code show icon app
        Icon (
            painter = painterResource (id = R.drawable.app_logo),
            contentDescription = null,
            tint = Color.White,
            modifier = Modifier.size (100.dp)
        )
        Spacer(modifier = Modifier.height(20.dp))
        Column(
            modifier = Modifier.fillMaxWidth(),
            verticalArrangement = Arrangement.spacedBy(8.dp)
        ) {

            Button(
                onClick = { /*TODO*/ },
                modifier = Modifier
                    .fillMaxWidth()
                    .height(48.dp),
                colors = ButtonDefaults.buttonColors(

                    contentColor = Color.White,
                    containerColor = Color(0xFF6BBB6B)
                )
            ) {
                Text(text = "Đăng ký miễn phí")
            }
            OptionButton(modifier = Modifier,title="Tiếp tục với Google", icon= R.drawable.google_icon)
            OptionButton(modifier = Modifier,title="Tiếp tục với Facebook", icon= R.drawable.facebook_icon)
            OptionButton(modifier = Modifier,title="Tiếp tục với Apple", icon= R.drawable.apple_icon)
            TextButton(
                onClick = { /*TODO*/ },
                modifier = Modifier
                    .fillMaxWidth()
                    .height(48.dp),
            ) {
                Text(text = "Đăng nhập", color = Color(0xFFFFFFFF))
            }
        }
    }
}
@Composable
fun OptionButton(modifier: Modifier = Modifier,title: String, icon:Int){
    Button(
        onClick = { /*TODO*/ },
        modifier = Modifier
            .fillMaxWidth()
            .height(48.dp),
        colors = ButtonDefaults.buttonColors(
            contentColor = Color.White,//toàn bộ nội dung trong Button là màu đen
            containerColor = Color.Transparent// làm cho nền button trong suốt
        ),
        border = BorderStroke(0.5.dp, Color.White)
    ) {
        Row(
            modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize(),
            horizontalArrangement = Arrangement.Start,
            verticalAlignment = Alignment.CenterVertically,
        ) {
            Image(painter = painterResource(id = icon), contentDescription = null,
                modifier = Modifier.size(32.dp))
            Text(text = title,modifier=Modifier.align(Alignment.CenterVertically))
        }
    }
}
@Composable
fun Theme_login(modifier: Modifier = Modifier){
    Box(modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize()){
        Image(
            painter = painterResource(id = R.drawable.monster_poster),
            contentDescription = null,
            contentScale = ContentScale.Crop,
            modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize().drawWithContent {
                drawContent()//modifier để làm mờ dần nữa màn hình dưới
                val brush = Brush.verticalGradient(
                    colors = listOf(Color.Transparent, Color.White),
                    startY = 0f,
                    endY = size.height * 0.5f
                )
                drawRect(
                    brush = brush,
                    blendMode = BlendMode.DstIn
                )
            }
        )
        LoginScreen()
    }
}


@Preview(showBackground = true)
@Composable
fun GreetingPreview() {
    Theme_login()
}
```

Please help me.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68731815/how-to-center-horizontally-and-vertically-text-in-jetpack-compose-text/68733149#68733149

Comment: The code works fine if I remove all the modifier chains, if I keep it the text is lost. Is there any other solution besides covering Text() in Box() sir?
The code works fine if I remove all the modifier chains, if I keep it the text is lost. Is there any other solution besides covering Text() in Box() sir?

Comment: You can check whether the answer here will work for you. Let the text fill the whole width and give a text alignment of center. 

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77506832/how-to-align-the-text-inside-a-text-button-at-startleft-end-of-the-screen/77506951#77506951